# Hibernate Unknown column field list "clazz_"

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, nhibernate-mapping

As a beginner, I'm doing a small project for educational purpose : a **Login / Registration form** using Spring MVC / Hibernate.

Before digging in the problem, I will show you my **Entity–relationship** & **Relational** model. *For registration*, I will create an *Account* object and *setRole("USER")*.

The ER model:

[image]

And its translation to RM model:

[image]

**NOW LET'S DIG IN THE CODE !**

For our context we will focus on these Entities

```
Account.java
MemberAccount.java  (extending Account.java)
Role.java
LogEntry.java
```

***The BUSINESS LOGIC:***

```
@Service
public class AccountRegistrationServiceImpl implements RegistrationService<Object> {

@Autowired
private AccountRepository mAccountRepository;

@Autowired
private RoleRepository mRoleRepository;


// Method used to insert record
public void register(Object obj) {
    Account account = (Account) obj;

    account.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(mRoleRepository.findAllByDescription("USER")));
    account.setType("DirectLogin");

    mAccountRepository.save(account);
}


// Find an existing 'mailAccount' (-> an User is already registered with this mail account) 
public List<Object> checkIfAccountExists(Object obj) {
    String mailAccount = (String) obj;
    
    return mAccountRepository.findByMailAccount(mailAccount);
}
}



public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Long> {
    // SELECT r1_0.id, r1_0.description FROM role as r1_0 WHERE r1_0.description = roleDescription
    public List<Role> findAllByDescription(String roleDescription);
}

public interface AccountRepositoryextends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {
    public List<Object> findByMailAccount(String emailAccount);
}
```

***Account.java***

```
 @Data                                        // Lombok library to avoid writing getter/setter
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "account")
 @Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
 @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
 public class Account {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "accountType")
private String type;

@Column(name = "availability")
private Boolean availability;

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
private String mailAccount;

@Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
private String userName;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Transient                                  // Will not be persisted
private String passwordConfirm;


@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "hasRoles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "aId", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rId", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<Role> roles;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private List<LogEntry> logs;
}
```

***MemberAccount.java***

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "memberAccount")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class MemberAccount extends Account {

/*
 * 'id' and 'type' are defined from Account.java.
 * 
 * In DB language: They have their own id' and 'type' columns.
 */


@Column(name = "firstname")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "birthDate")
private String birthDate;

@Column(name = "gender")
private String gender;

@Column(name = "civilstatus")
private String civilStatus;

@Column(name = "profession")
private String profession;

@Column(name = "street")
private String streetName;

@Column(name = "streetNbr")
private String streetNumber;

@Column(name = "city")
private String city;

@Column(name = "zip")
private String zipCode;

@Column(name = "country")
private String country;

}
```

***Role.java***

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class Role {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private Set<Account> accounts;
}
```

***LogEntry.java***

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "logEntry")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class LogEntry {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "affiliatedUserId")
private Account user;

@Column(name = "loginDate")
private Date loginDate;

@Column(name = "logoutDate")
private Date logoutDate;

}
```

***AND ... our SQL script***

```
DROP DATABASE springlogin_db;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS springlogin_db

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account;
CREATE TABLE account (
    id BIGINT,
    accountType varchar(20),
    availability boolean,
    userName varchar(30),
    email varchar(30),
    password varchar(20)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS role;
CREATE TABLE role (
    id BIGINT,
    description varchar(20))
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hasRoles;
CREATE TABLE hasRoles (
    aId BIGINT,
    rId BIGINT)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS logEntry;
CREATE TABLE logEntry (
   id BIGINT,
   affiliatedUserId BIGINT,
   loginDate DATE,
   logoutDate DATE)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS memberAccount;
CREATE TABLE memberAccount (
    id BIGINT,
    accountType varchar(20),
    firstname varchar(20),
    lastname varchar(20),
    birthDate varchar(11),
    gender varchar(10),
    civilstatus varchar(10),
    profession varchar(20),
    street varchar(30),
    streetNbr int,
    city varchar(20),
    zip int,
    country varchar(20))
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


ALTER TABLE account
ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);

ALTER TABLE role
ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);

ALTER TABLE hasRoles
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_hasRoles_accountId_id FOREIGN KEY(aId) REFERENCES account(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE hasRoles
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_hasRoles_roleId_id FOREIGN KEY(rId) REFERENCES role(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE logEntry
ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);
ALTER TABLE logEntry
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_logEntry_affiliatedUserId_id FOREIGN KEY(affiliatedUserId) REFERENCES account(id);

ALTER TABLE memberAccount
ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);


INSERT INTO role
VALUES ('1', 'USER'),('2', 'ADMIN');
```

When looking for 'USER' role, my app will execute

```
account.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(mRoleRepository.findAllByDescription("USER")));
```

Here some SQL Hibernate is doing behind:

```
select
    r1_0.id,
    r1_0.description 
from
    role as r1_0 
where
    r1_0.description = ?
```

Before proceeding to the rest of the code, my app crash at this moment:

```
select
    a1_0.rId,
    a1_1.id,
    a1_1.clazz_,
    a1_1.availability,
    a1_1.email,
    a1_1.password,
    a1_1.accountType,
    a1_1.username,
    a1_2.birthDate,
    a1_2.city,
    a1_2.civilstatus,
    a1_2.country,
    a1_2.firstname,
    a1_2.gender,
    a1_2.lastname,
    a1_2.profession,
    a1_2.street,
    a1_2.streetNbr,
    a1_2.zip 
from
    hasRoles as a1_0 
left outer join
    account as a1_1 
        on a1_0.aId = a1_1.id 
left outer join
    memberAccount as a1_2 
        on a1_1.id = a1_2.id 
where
    a1_0.rId = ?
```

I suspect that Hibernate create this **"clazz_" column** but I can't see what am I missing in my code. Sorry for writing this LONG post.

Best regards

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace error ?

Comment: @antoine.lange Thank you for your reply. To begin, when the future member has entered a UserName, a Password, an Email Account, the Web app will proceed to INSERT record into the DB. Please wait I will add the log

Comment: @antoine.lange I copied / paste the full log on https://pastebin.com/8dyAFyGA  .Don't hesitate to ask me for more details because I tried to not writing the code comments in my post (also the Logger from Log4j library).